# Create 2 packet group 100

Tags: irobot-create

I tried getting pack sensors for packet group 100. What I noticed was the order of the packets did not match what's in the document. Anyone notice the same problem?

For example here is the output of packet group 6 & 101 - which should be the same at 100 but that's not the case. It would seem like the order of the packets are not the same in group 100.

Here is packet group 6:

```
2017/05/31 193538 PACKET GROUP 6 len:52
        Bump & Wheel Drop:  0  - 1
                     Wall:  0  - 1
               Cliff Left:  0  - 1
         Cliff Front Left:  0  - 1
        Cliff Front Right:  0  - 1
              Cliff Right:  0  - 1
             Virtual Wall:  0  - 1
        Wheel Overcurrent:  0  - 1
              Dirt Detect:  0  - 1
                 Unused 1:  0  - 1
             Omni IR Code:  161  - 1
                  Buttons:  0  - 1
                 Distance:  0 - 2
                    Angle:  0 - 2
                 Charging:  0  - 1
                  Voltage:  15140 - 2
                  Current:  -211 - 2
              Temperature:  25  - 1
           Battery Charge:  2234 - 2
         Battery Capacity:  2696 - 2
              Wall Signal:  0 - 2
        Cliff Left Signal:  2938 - 2
  Cliff Front Left Signal:  2047 - 2
 Cliff Front Right Signal:  1399 - 2
       Cliff Right Signal:  2232 - 2
                 Unused 2:  0  - 1
                 Unused 3:  0 - 2
          Charging Source:  0  - 1
                  OI Mode:  1  - 1
              Song Number:  0  - 1
             Song Playing:  0  - 1
       Num Stream Packets:  0  - 1
            Req. Velocity:  0 - 2
              Req. Radius:  0 - 2
      Req. Right Velocity:  0 - 2
       Req. Left Velocity:  0 - 2
```

Here is packet group 101:

```
2017/05/31 193859 PACKET GROUP 101 len:28
             Left Encoder:  10 - 2
            Right Encoder:  6 - 2
                   Bumper:  0  - 1
       Bumper Left Signal:  11 - 2
 Bumper Front Left Signal:  6 - 2
Bumper Center Left Signal:  8 - 2
Bumper Center Right Signal:  0 - 2
Bumper Front Right Signal:  11 - 2
      Bumper Right Signal:  0 - 2
             IR Code Left:  0  - 1
            IR Code Right:  0  - 1
       Left Motor Current:  0 - 2
      Right Motor Current:  0 - 2
       Main Brush Current:  0 - 2
       Side Brush Current:  0 - 2
                   Stasis:  0  - 1
```

And here is packet group 100:

```
2017/05/31 193654 PACKET GROUP 100 len:80
        Bump & Wheel Drop:  0  - 1
                     Wall:  0  - 1
               Cliff Left:  0  - 1
         Cliff Front Left:  0  - 1
        Cliff Front Right:  0  - 1
              Cliff Right:  0  - 1
             Virtual Wall:  0  - 1
        Wheel Overcurrent:  0  - 1
              Dirt Detect:  0  - 1
                 Unused 1:  0  - 1
             Omni IR Code:  161  - 1
                  Buttons:  0  - 1
                 Distance:  0 - 2
                    Angle:  0 - 2
                 Charging:  0  - 1
                  Voltage:  15140 - 2
                  Current:  -219 - 2
              Temperature:  25  - 1
           Battery Charge:  2230 - 2
         Battery Capacity:  2696 - 2
              Wall Signal:  0 - 2
        Cliff Left Signal:  2950 - 2
  Cliff Front Left Signal:  2198 - 2
 Cliff Front Right Signal:  0 - 2
       Cliff Right Signal:  3072 - 2
                 Unused 2:  0  - 1
                 Unused 3:  0 - 2
          Charging Source:  0  - 1
                  OI Mode:  0  - 1
              Song Number:  0  - 1
             Song Playing:  0  - 1
       Num Stream Packets:  0  - 1
            Req. Velocity:  0 - 2
              Req. Radius:  0 - 2
      Req. Right Velocity:  0 - 2
       Req. Left Velocity:  0 - 2

             Left Encoder:  8 - 2
            Right Encoder:  4 - 2
                   Bumper:  0  - 1
       Bumper Left Signal:  11 - 2
 Bumper Front Left Signal:  6 - 2
Bumper Center Left Signal:  9 - 2
Bumper Center Right Signal:  0 - 2
Bumper Front Right Signal:  0 - 2
      Bumper Right Signal:  0 - 2
             IR Code Left:  0  - 1
            IR Code Right:  0  - 1
       Left Motor Current:  0 - 2
      Right Motor Current:  0 - 2
       Main Brush Current:  0 - 2
       Side Brush Current:  0 - 2
                   Stasis:  0  - 1
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Deepak, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an order difference in the list you have posted here, so I'm not sure what your question is.

I also went back and checked the original source code (I am the author) and there is no discrepancy. The contents of packets 6 + 101 do equal packet 100.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I should have explained the output better. Let me call out the specific parts.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I should have explained the output better. Let me call out the specific parts.    In the output if you look at the cliff signal output between packet 6 and packet 100 there is a difference. I am running firmware 3.5.  The simplest way to replicate this  problem might be to request all the cliff signal data directly, via packet 6 and packet 100. That was how I discovered the issue

Comment: Are you talking about the cliff signal values? Those are sampled faster than the robot's usual 15 ms tick, so if you request the cliff signal twice in one 15 ms time slot you could get two different values for the same cliff sensor.